# How to align multiple images horizontally (in a row)?

Tags: css, image, alignment, overflow

How can one align multiple images, one after another, horizontally? They don't have to fit the width screen: on the contrary, I would like to have them exceed the width of the latter, if that makes any sens.

I have checked quite a few answers to similar questions but couldn't find any that would fix my problem.

Html:

```
<div id="content">
    <img src="Content/Images/Personal/Georges.jpg" alt="Georges" class="images" />
    <img src="Content/Images/Personal/Rose.jpg" alt="Gers" class="images" />
    <img src="Content/Images/Personal/Henry.jpg" alt="Providence" class="images" />
</div>
```

Css:

```
.images
{
display: inline;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#content
{
display: block;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
top: 90px;
height: auto;
max-width: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x:auto;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Effectively, you want to prevent the `inline` `img` elements from wrapping, as such, you want to use the below on the parent `#content` element:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/s7my93yq/)

[More on `white-space` from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

> **nowrap** Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks
>   (wrapping).

This style is specifically for the purpose you require.

Answer (score 4):

edit css of image as:

```
.images
{
display: inline-block;
float:left;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to align the images in one line. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dayuhaxu/1/edit)** using `display:inline-block` Method.

```
1. using `float:left` /*you have to clear the float using `overflow:hidden` on parent element */
2. using `display:inline-block`
3. using `Flex` /*Its a new CSS3 property */
```

**Note:**  I would suggest you as per your requirement you should change your HTML markup and need to use `ul` listing here.

Comment: Using float:left, I was only able to get them on top of eachothers; display: inline-block didn't help me either, however, I don't know about Flex? There must be something wrong earlier in my code or, I don't understand. Thank you for your answer

Comment: you have to used `overflow:hidden` on parent element.

Comment: `Flex` /*Its a new CSS3 property*/

Comment: I'll have to look that property up, thank you for your help Kheema !

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/us8paazd/)**

CSS:

```
#content img
{
display: inline-block;
    margin-right:5px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just by changing `display: block;` and adding `float:left` attribute to css `.images` class