# Two images in <picture> srcset

Tags: html, tags

how can I insert two images for the desktop version (one on the right and the other on the left) in the picture tag that replace the only of the mobile version?

I tried that but it doesn't work.

```
    <picture>
      <source media="(max-width: 375px)" srcset="./assets/illustration-hero-mobile.png">
      <source media="(min-width: 376px)" srcset="./assets/illustration-hero-right.svg">
      <source media="(min-width: 376px)" srcset="./assets/illustration-hero-left.svg">
      <img src="./assets/illustration-hero-mobile.png" alt="hero-image">
    </picture>
```

Thank you

Comment: read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202348/how-to-align-multiple-images-horizontally-in-a-row

Comment: Hi, I looked but this doesn't help me: I have to show two images in the desktop version instead of just one in the mobile version and with my code only one is displayed also in the desktop version

Comment: How does it not work? I've tested the code, and it appears to work. Make sure the image paths are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Read this one :
[https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_media.asp#:~:text=The%20media%20attribute%20specifies%20what](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_media.asp#:%7E:text=The%20media%20attribute%20specifies%20what)
media does't supported with source element in many browser.
You might want to try !  this with css.

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .desktop{
        display: none;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .mobile{
        display: none;
    }
}

</style>
<picture>
  <img class="desktop" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">
  <img class="desktop" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300">
  <img class="mobile" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale">
</picture>
```